# Why Skip Kabbalas Shabbos on Yom Tov?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, yom-tov, provenance, kabbalat-shabbat

In my experience among all Ashkenaz shuls across America, it seems we skip Kabbalas Shabbos when shabbos falls out on Yom Tov. Where did this come from and why?

Comment: In my experience in Ashkenazi synagogues, we skip *most of* it. But YMMV.